# Is there a way to open a desktop app as a "subview" inside a Tauri app?

Tags: iframe, rust, webview, tauri

I am building my first app with Tauri framework. Basically, I would like to open as embedded "subviews" (as for "IFrame", just to be clear), inside the main page, two desktop apps, and manage their interactions.
Assuming it is possible, could you give me some hint about?

As always, hoping the question is not too trivial, thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want it all to be in the same window or you're thinking in a multi-window app?